# Django Foreign Key Aliasing

Tags: django

I'm trying to be able to alias a column name from a model's foreign key.  I want to be able to change 'owner__username' to just 'username' when passing a JSON response.

```
query_n = Example.objects.values('owner__username','name')
print(query_n[0])
```

Which prints

```
{'name': 'e_adam', 'owner__username': 'adam'}
```

The only renaming of a column I have seen was via ***annotate()*** however, that isn't even truly a column (AVG, SUM, ...)


The Example model has a foreign key owner, which is 'auth.User' model.


Any thoughts?

Comment: check out related_name: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: How does that help? I'm trying to access 'username' via the foreign key 'owner'.  I'm using 'auth.User', fyi

Answer (score 3):

I'm not too sure about this but if you are using django >= 1.7, sounds like you could use `annotate` to create alias for named arguments in `values()`. I found a related django [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16735), to quote from the latest response:

> Just quickly, with the changes to annotate that have landed, it is now
>   possible to create aliases yourself, and reference them from the
>   values call:

```
from django.db.models import F
Model.objects.annotate(my_alias=F('some__long__name__to__alias')) \
             .values('my_alias')
```

Comment: Thanks Shang Wang,
Your answer help me very much

Answer (score 0):

```
aliasName = models.ForeignKey(modelName, to_field='fieldName', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is the format for aliasing in Django Foreign Key
Here is full Models page

```
 from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Farm(models.Model):
    srFarm  = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name    = models.CharField(max_length = 264, unique =True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 264)

    def __str__(self):
        temp = '{0.name},{0.address}'
        return temp.format(self)


class Batch(models.Model):
    srBatch = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    farmName = models.ForeignKey(Farm, to_field='name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        temp = '{0.farmName}'
        return temp.format(self)
```